# About the GMRFlib

Tags: normal-distribution, matlab, c++

I am trying to access the GMRFlib as mentioned in the link http://www.math.ntnu.no/~hrue/GMRFsim/doc/html/. However, I think it is not available anymore. I couldn't see the tarball mentioned. Does anyone have access to it?

Answer (score 2):

Its author has incorporated it into a Google Code project: http://code.google.com/p/inla/source/browse/gmrflib